# Search paths where all nodes are in a relationship with same node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Using the below graph as an example: I am trying to determine all ***Persons*** which ***are_sons*** of ***Persons*** all ***born*** in the same country:

[image: Graph]

Is there an elegant way to achieve this with Cypher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like

```
match (c:Country)
with c
MATCH (kid:Person)-[:IS_SON]-(par:Person)
WITH c,kid, collect(distinct par) as parents
match (kid)
where all(x in parents WHERE  (x)-[:WAS_BORN]-(c))
return c, collect(kid) as kids
```

this should return a list or records each containing a person whos all of his parents were born in the USA

Comment: Hi. What I want is for Ann to be returned because all her parents were born in the USA. This is not going to help, right?

Comment: misread the question and updated the answer to reflect your comment ( i hope )  :)

Comment: This is helpful. But I don't the query to be restricted to the USA. This picture is just an example.

Comment: updated the answer to return a list of countries and the kids born there